# Front nodejs (vue) и Spring end безопасность взаимодействия

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, spring-security

Хочу разработать фронт на Vue.js, который крутится на Node.js. Серверная часть будет на Spring Boot через REST API. Сам вопрос у меня в том, как организовать безопасность обмена между клиентской и серверной частями?

Ранее делал через JSP, там подключал Spring Security, генерил страницу на сервере вместе с токенами, через security раздавал роли. Как тут быть не знаю, единственное, что приходит в голову, так это OAuth, выдавать токен пользователю и по этому токену доступ к определённым функциям.

Может и другие подходы есть, кто какие практике использовал, опишите. Но хотелось бы серверную часть от клиентской отделить.

Comment: В чем проблема генерить для разных ролей коды, и вставлять их в запросах к серверу, а сервер перед выполнением каждого запроса проверяет его код? Если не высоконагруженный сервер, то на перфомансе не скажется.

Comment: Вариант конечно интересный, но получается, что мне надо знать коды и на клиентской части и на серверной, так то проще хранить токен для пользователя, который к тому же выдаётся на определённое время. Если один токен на одну роль, а у меня какое-нибудь действие для нескольких ролей, то в запросе это надо всё указать, как то некрасиво выходит мне кажется

Comment: Не всегда то, что работает - выглядит красиво.

Answer (score 1):

Собственнон говоря Spring Security накидывается на API таким же образом как на MVC контроллер, вы можете использовать сессию для хранения вошедшего пользователя или без сесии. Это зависит от типа аудентификации. На фронте надо писать классы для аудитентификации и сервис, который выполняет ее. Затем пользователя сохраняют в `localStorage` тем же самым сервисом, который определяет объект вошедшего пользователя. Вы можете всегда получить такого пользователя через сервис, а также роли, которыми он обладает, даже после рефреша страницы, если это надо.